# How to solve 500 undefined message YII?

Tags: yii

I'm working on `YII` and I get `500 Undefined Message`. It does not tell me a lot. How can I get what's the problem? Is there `any debug mode` for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be the PHP Notice.

Due to undefined variables it is coming.

Put these below line in index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Should be like this

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable `YII_DEBUG` in your `index.php` to receive the full trace. This should help you to find out, where the error occured exactly. Be sure to not do this on your production machine, though, as it may echo sensible data like DB credentials to the screen.

`define('YII_DEBUG', true);`